# XML error Element type "links" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

Tags: xml

Hi guys I was wondering why I'm getting below error with below XML:

```
7:  88  Element type "links" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
```

Is there a reason why this is happening with below XML code?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><start>
    <firstName>Jae</firstName>
    <lastName>Choi</lastName>
    <companyName>Test Company</companyName>
    <location>Melbourne</location>
    <contacts Phone="12345" Mobile="12312123" Text="" Email=""></contacts>
    <links Facebook="" Twitter="" Site="appscore.com.au" LinkedIn="" test="test12311.com" 1231="hello.com"></links>
    <frontCard>http://blink.wmetools.com/img/cards/Test123_front.png</frontCard>
    <backCard>http://blink.wmetools.com/img/cards/Test123_back.png</backCard>
    <cardID>Test123</cardID>
</start>
```

Comment: Is `1231` a valid attribute name?

Comment: Attribute names cannot start with a digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML names cannot start with digits, so your XML is not well formed, which is why you are getting the error.

See the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-NameStartChar).

Answer (score 2):

Running xmllint I get:

```
xml.xml:7: parser error : error parsing attribute name
  Facebook="" Twitter="" Site="appscore.com.au" LinkedIn="" test="test12311.com"
```

Numbers are not valid attribute [name start characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-NameStartChar).